# Data Visualization issue with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-analysis

I'm a student of Python and I'm trying to visualize some data with matplotlib.

In my Jupyter notebook my chart shows like this:

[image]

But I need my chart to be like this:

[image]

I have created Google Colab for share the code

Please let me know what I have done wrong here

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YG4tmO9v0jEex9kzdAvTKXcdxwLBpWoo?usp=sharing

Comment: Try to use `seaborn.countplot` [doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html)

Comment: Please share code and test data as text directly into your post, not as a link to information that is short-lived.

Comment: There is a code example in the `matplotlib` docs -> https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py . According to it, it's necessary to create the `bar_labes` to separate the data in different bar groups.